# fail2ban too slow, banning after the attack

Tags: fail2ban

We had a "register"-attack to our voip server (freeswitch).
In the Logs it looks something like this:

```
2019-04-25 14:35:16.137965 [WARNING] sofia_reg.c:1743 SIP auth failure (REGISTER) on sofia profile 'internal' for [309@123.123.123.123] from ip 77.247.108.59
```

For this purpose, we have Fail2Ban, which should block this IP after 10 tries.
But this doesn't work.

Fail2Ban writes many "found" entries in the log file. After several thousand entries and a slow server because of Fail2Ban, the last entry is "Ban [ip]":

```
2019-04-25 14:37:18,961 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:19
2019-04-25 14:37:18,994 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:19
2019-04-25 14:37:19,033 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:19
2019-04-25 14:37:19,068 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:19
2019-04-25 14:37:19,114 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:19
2019-04-25 14:37:19,152 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:20
2019-04-25 14:37:19,192 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:20
2019-04-25 14:37:19,232 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:20
2019-04-25 14:37:19,268 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:20
2019-04-25 14:37:19,302 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:20
2019-04-25 14:37:19,345 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:20
2019-04-25 14:37:19,384 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:20
2019-04-25 14:37:19,426 fail2ban.filter         [2167]: INFO    [freeswitch] Found 77.247.108.59 - 2019-04-25 14:35:20
2019-04-25 14:37:20,087 fail2ban.actions        [2167]: NOTICE  [freeswitch] Ban 77.247.108.59
```

Is this a fail of Fail2Ban or did I configure something wrong?

jail.local:

```
   [DEFAULT]
   ignoreip = [censored]
   ignorecommand = /usr/bin/php /etc/fail2ban/ignorecommands/freeswitch/check.php <ip>
   bantime  = 86400
   findtime = 3600
   maxretry = 10
   backend = auto
   usedns = warn
   banaction = iptables-multiport
   mta = sendmail
   protocol = tcp
   chain = INPUT
   action_ = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
   action_mw = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"] %(mta)s-whois[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]
   action_mwl = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s, port="%(port)s", protocol="%(protocol)s", chain="%(chain)s"] %(mta)s-whois-lines[name=%(__name__)s, dest="%(destemail)s", logpath=%(logpath)s, chain="%(chain)s", sendername="%(sendername)s"]
   action = %(action_)s
```

jail.d/freeswitch.local:

```
[freeswitch]
enabled = true
ignoreip = [censored]
ignorecommand = /usr/bin/php /etc/fail2ban/ignorecommands/freeswitch/check.php <ip>
maxretry = 10
findtime = 3600
bantime = 3600
port     = 5060,5061,5080,5081
action   = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s-tcp, port="%(port)s", protocol="tcp", chain="%(chain)s", actname=%(banaction)s-tcp] %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s-udp, port="%(port)s", protocol="udp", chain="%(chain)s", actname=%(banaction)s-udp]
logpath = /var/log/freeswitch/freeswitch.log
```

filter.d/freeswitch.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = \[WARNING\] sofia_reg\.c:\d+ SIP auth failure \(REGISTER\) on sofia profile \'[^']+\' for \[.*\] from ip <HOST>$
            \[WARNING\] sofia_reg\.c:\d+ SIP auth challenge \(INVITE\) on sofia profile \'[^']+\' for \[.*\] from ip <HOST>$
            \[WARNING\] sofia_reg\.c:\d+ Can't find user \[\d+@\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\] from <HOST>$
            \"FAIL2BAN_HOST=<HOST>\"
            IP <HOST> Rejected by acl
```

Debian 9
Fail2Ban v0.10.5.dev1

Comment: That log is not being flushed on disk

Comment: What log do you mean? the Fail2Ban or the freeswitch log?
And how should this help me, with the problem?